use osgGA::StateSetManipulator,Pressing T and L functions do not respond, why is this?
target:
Qt embeds osg for rendering. Use the osgQOpenGLWidget control to place into the QTabWidget control, a multi-page control that serves as the central widget of the QMainWindow subclass.
Finally, in view of the join osgGA: : StateSetManipulator object, for the operation of the state.
question:
Pressing w and b functions normally, but pressing T and L functions do not respond, why is this?
file:
These textures have texture!
// hpp file
class V3dViewerWidget : public QMainWindow 
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    V3dViewerWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    V3dViewerWidget(osg::ArgumentParser& arguments, QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    V3dViewerWidget(QString externalfile, QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    
    protected slots:
    void initData();
    
    private:
    void WidgetUIinit();
    void setCentralData();
    void setCentralData(osg::ArgumentParser& argument);
    
    private:
    QTabWidget* _mTabCenteralWidget = nullptr;
};

// cpp file
V3dViewerWidget::V3dViewerWidget(QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    WidgetUIinit();
    setCentralData();
}

V3dViewerWidget::V3dViewerWidget(osg::ArgumentParser& arguments, QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    WidgetUIinit();
    setCentralData(arguments);
}

V3dViewerWidget::V3dViewerWidget(QString externalfile, QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    WidgetUIinit();
    setCentralData();
}

void V3dViewerWidget::WidgetUIinit()
{
    #ifdef HIDE_COMPANY_INFO
    setWindowTitle(tr("Drone_image_modeling_tool") + tr(" Viewer")); //%1 Viewer
    #else
    setWindowTitle(QString("%1 Viewer").arg(PRODUCT_NAME));
    setWindowIcon(QIcon(VIEWER_ICON));
    #endif
    this->setMinimumSize(800, 600);
    // tab widget
    _mTabCenteralWidget = new QTabWidget(this);
    QPalette backcolor(QPalette::Background, Qt::darkGray);
    _mTabCenteralWidget->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    _mTabCenteralWidget->setPalette(backcolor);
    // V3d_Viewer centre widgte
    this->setCentralWidget(_mTabCenteralWidget);
}

void V3dViewerWidget::initData()
{
    // no run exe
    osgQOpenGLWidget* sender = dynamic_cast<osgQOpenGLWidget*>(QObject::sender());
    if (!sender)
        return;
}

void V3dViewerWidget::setCentralData()
{
    // create osgOpneGLwidget
    osgQOpenGLWidget widget;
    // init
    widget.setMouseTracking(true);
    widget.setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
    // data load
    connect(&widget, SIGNAL(initialized()), this, SLOT(initData()));
}

void V3dViewerWidget::setCentralData(osg::ArgumentParser& argument)
{
    // create osgOpneGLwidget
    osgQOpenGLWidget* widget = new osgQOpenGLWidget(&argument);
    // init
    widget->setMouseTracking(true);
    widget->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
    // add tab
    _mTabCenteralWidget->addTab(widget, "osgb_test");
    // data load
    connect(widget, &osgQOpenGLWidget::initialized, [&argument, widget]() 
    {
    // set viewer manipator and event
    osgViewer::Viewer* viewer = widget->getOsgViewer();
    widget->getOsgViewer()->addEventHandler(new osgGA::StateSetManipulator(viewer->getCamera()->getOrCreateStateSet()));
    widget->getOsgViewer()->setCameraManipulator(new osgGA::TrackballManipulator());
    // add tabwidget
    osg::ref_ptr<osg::Node> loadedModel = osgDB::readNodeFile("D:/x/View_test/test.osgb");
    // osg::ref_ptr<osg::Node> loadedModel = osgDB::readRefNodeFiles(argument);
    if (!loadedModel) 
    {
        return;
    }
    osgUtil::Optimizer optimizer;
    optimizer.optimize(loadedModel);
    // set data
    widget->getOsgViewer()->setSceneData(loadedModel.get());
});
}
// main function：
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
// opengl set
    QSurfaceFormat format = QSurfaceFormat::defaultFormat();
    
    #ifdef OSG_GL3_AVAILABLE
    format.setVersion(3, 2);
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
    format.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL);
    format.setOption(QSurfaceFormat::DebugContext);
    #else
    format.setVersion(2, 0);
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile);
    format.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL);
    format.setOption(QSurfaceFormat::DebugContext);
    #endif
    format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    // format.setAlphaBufferSize(8);
    format.setSamples(8);
    format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
    format.setSwapBehavior(QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
    // app
    QApplication qapp(argc, argv);
    
    // show widget
    osg::ArgumentParser arguments(&argc, argv);
    V3dViewerWidget     w(arguments);
    w.show();
    return qapp.exec();
}

other instance*:*
This is another instance, osgGA::StateSetManipulator function of a class without any problems!
These textures have texture!
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QSurfaceFormat format = QSurfaceFormat::defaultFormat();
    
    #ifdef OSG_GL3_AVAILABLE
    format.setVersion(3, 2);
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
    format.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL);
    format.setOption(QSurfaceFormat::DebugContext);
    #else
    format.setVersion(2, 0);
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile);
    format.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL);
    format.setOption(QSurfaceFormat::DebugContext);
    #endif
    format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    // format.setAlphaBufferSize(8);
    format.setSamples(8);
    format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
    format.setSwapBehavior(QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
    QApplication qapp(argc, argv);
    //
    QTabWidget Twidget;
    
    osgQOpenGLWidget mwidget;
    osgQOpenGLWidget ms_widget;
    mwidget.setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
    ms_widget.setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
    
    Twidget.addTab(&mwidget, "osgb_test");
    Twidget.addTab(&ms_widget, "ply_test");

    QObject::connect(&mwidget, &osgQOpenGLWidget::initialized, [&]() 
   {
        osgViewer::Viewer* viewer = mwidget.getOsgViewer();
        if (!viewer) 
        {
            qWarning("Failed to get OSG Viewer");
            return -1;
        }
        viewer->setCameraManipulator(new osgGA::TrackballManipulator());
        viewer->addEventHandler(new osgGA::StateSetManipulator(viewer->getCamera()->getOrCreateStateSet()));
        osg::ref_ptr<osg::Node> loadedModel = osgDB::readNodeFile("D:/x/View_test/test.osgb");
        osgUtil::Optimizer optimizer;
        optimizer.optimize(loadedModel);
        viewer->setSceneData(loadedModel);
        return 0;
    });

    QObject::connect(&ms_widget, &osgQOpenGLWidget::initialized, [&]() 
    {
        osgViewer::Viewer* viewer = ms_widget.getOsgViewer();
        if (!viewer) 
        {
            qWarning("Failed to get OSG Viewer");
            return -1;
        }
        viewer->setCameraManipulator(new osgGA::TrackballManipulator());
        osgGA::StateSetManipulator* state = new osgGA::StateSetManipulator(viewer->getCamera()->getOrCreateStateSet()
        viewer->addEventHandler(state);
        osg::ref_ptr<osg::Node> loadedModel = osgDB::readNodeFile("E:/x/mesh.ply");      
        osgUtil::Optimizer optimizer;
        optimizer.optimize(loadedModel);
        viewer->setSceneData(loadedModel);
        return 0;
    });
    Twidget.show();
    return qapp.exec();
}


osg version is 3.6.5

Sorry but your question is unclear. What do you mean by "T and L functions"? Are you referring to key press events? Please take your time to [edit] your post in order to carefully explain your question and eventually consider to provide a proper [mre]. Environment details must also be in the question, not in comments.

T Key's function:Toggle the state with or without texture!

L Key's function:With or without light state switching!
